# Why the border is not coming for pdf pages created by itextsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

This is the code I use to create a pdf file. This works good, and the pdf file is in more than one page.

I do have the table in the pdf file, the table is starting from page 1 and goes to last page (i.e, page 3). So the border of the page is closing on the page 2.

It would be good if I have the table border on page 2. Can any one please help me how can I have have border on all the pages?

Thanks much in advance.

```
 public void Masterpdffile(DataTable dtpdfvalues, InvoiceSchema     _InvoiceSchema, Companyschema _Companyschema)
    {
        string Filename = string.Empty;
        string FilePath = string.Empty;
       try
        {



         MemoryStream PDFData = new MemoryStream();
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 40, 40);
            string ApplicationPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "Logo.png";
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, PDFData);


            var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
            var titleFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var boldTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var boldTableFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var boldTableFont2 = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var Total = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
            var boldTableFont3 = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var bodyFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var italicFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
           var Font =FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 12,BaseColor.WHITE);

               var border =(PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER);

            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = writer.PageSize;

            Filename = _InvoiceSchema.InvoiceNumber+"-"+"Masterpackingslip"+"-" + DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + ".pdf";
            FilePath = Constant.Folderpath + "\\" + Filename;
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new System.IO.FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));

            doc.Open();

            #region Image and Title
            float[] phWidth = new float[] { 50f, 30f, 20f };
            PdfPTable Pheader = new PdfPTable(3);
            Pheader.WidthPercentage = 100f;
            Pheader.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;


            string Companyaddress = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address1))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address1 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address2))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address2 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address3))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address3 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address4))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address4 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address5))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Address5 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.City))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.City + ",";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.State))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.State + " ";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.PostalCode))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.PostalCode + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Country))
                Companyaddress += _Companyschema.Qbcompanyaddress.Country + Environment.NewLine;




            PdfPCell pcellsContect = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_Companyschema.CompanyName+ Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Companyaddress, bodyFont1));


            pcellsContect.PaddingLeft = 50;
            pcellsContect.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            pcellsContect.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pcellsContect.UseAscender = true;


            Pheader.AddCell(pcellsContect);






            PdfPCell pspac = new PdfPCell();
            pspac.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pspac.VerticalAlignment = 1;

            PdfPCell pInvoicez = new PdfPCell();
            pInvoicez.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pInvoicez.VerticalAlignment = 1;

            PdfPCell pcellsforspace = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("     Master Packing Slip", titleFont));
            pcellsforspace.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pcellsforspace.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
            pcellsforspace.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            pcellsforspace.UseDescender = true;

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Packing Slip", titleFont);

            p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            p1.Font = boldTableFont;
            pInvoicez.AddElement(p1);




            Pheader.AddCell(pspac);

            Pheader.AddCell(pcellsforspace);

            doc.Add(Pheader);
            #endregion











            #region Top
            float[] outwodth = new float[] { 50f, 20f, 30f };

            PdfPTable Outer = new PdfPTable(3);
            Outer.WidthPercentage = 100;
            Outer.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            Outer.SetWidths(outwodth);

            float[] wid = new float[] { 50f, 50f };


            PdfPTable pdf = new PdfPTable(2);
            pdf.SetWidths(wid);
            pdf.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pdf.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pdf.WidthPercentage = 90.0f;
            PdfPCell pcel = new PdfPCell();
            float[] widtSp = new float[] { 10f };
            PdfPTable pdfSpace = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdfSpace.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pdfSpace.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            pdfSpace.WidthPercentage = 5.0f;
            pdfSpace.SetWidths(widtSp);


            float[] widt = new float[] { 10f, 10f };
            PdfPTable ptable = new PdfPTable(2);
            ptable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            ptable.WidthPercentage = 5.0f;
            ptable.SetWidths(widt);
           PdfPCell pcellsDate = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsDate.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsDate.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellsDate.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsDate.FixedHeight = 20f;
            ptable.AddCell(pcellsDate);
            PdfPCell pcellsInvoice = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invoice #", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsInvoice.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsInvoice.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellsInvoice.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsInvoice.FixedHeight = 20f;


            ptable.AddCell(pcellsInvoice);

            PdfPCell pcellsDateValue = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_InvoiceSchema.InvoiceDate.ToShortDateString(), bodyFont));
            pcellsDateValue.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsDateValue.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            pcellsDateValue.PaddingLeft=10;
            pcellsDateValue.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsDateValue.FixedHeight = 20f;
            ptable.AddCell(pcellsDateValue);






            PdfPCell pcellsInvValue = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_InvoiceSchema.InvoiceNumber, bodyFont));
            pcellsInvValue.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsInvValue.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellsInvValue.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsInvValue.FixedHeight = 20f;
            ptable.AddCell(pcellsInvValue);




            Outer.AddCell(pdf);
            Outer.AddCell(pdfSpace);
            Outer.AddCell(ptable);
            Outer.SpacingAfter = 10f;
            doc.Add(Outer);
            #endregion

            #region Bill Mid table
            float[] widthBP = new float[] { 40f, 20f, 40f };
            PdfPTable tableBP = new PdfPTable(3);

            tableBP.WidthPercentage = 100;
            tableBP.SetWidths(widthBP);

            tableBP.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;


            float[] widp = new float[] { 20f };
            PdfPTable pdfpSp = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdfpSp.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pdfpSp.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            pdfpSp.WidthPercentage = 5.0f;
            pdfpSp.SetWidths(widp);


            string billaddress = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address1))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address1 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address2))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address2 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address3))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address3 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address4))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address4 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address5))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Address5 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.City))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.City + ",";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.State))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.State + " ";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.PostalCode))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.PostalCode + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Country))
                billaddress += _InvoiceSchema.BillAddress.Country + Environment.NewLine;

            float[] width = new float[] { 5f };
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            table.WidthPercentage = 5.0f;
            table.SetWidths(width);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.FixedHeight = 15f;

            PdfPCell pcellsBillTO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("   Bill To", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsBillTO.Colspan = 2;
            pcellsBillTO.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

            pcellsBillTO.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellsBillTO.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsBillTO.FixedHeight = 22f;
            table.AddCell(pcellsBillTO);


            PdfPCell pcellsBillTOvalue = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(billaddress, bodyFont));
            pcellsBillTOvalue.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pcellsBillTOvalue.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            pcellsBillTOvalue.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsBillTOvalue.FixedHeight = 50f;
            //madhu
            table.AddCell(pcellsBillTOvalue);

            float[] customerwidth = new float[] { 10f, 10f };
            PdfPTable ptablecustomer = new PdfPTable(2);
            ptablecustomer.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            ptablecustomer.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
            ptablecustomer.WidthPercentage = 15f;
            ptablecustomer.SetWidths(customerwidth);





            PdfPCell pcellscustomervalue = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer S.O", bodyFont));
            pcellscustomervalue.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellscustomervalue.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellscustomervalue.UseAscender = true;
            pcellscustomervalue.FixedHeight = 20f;

            ptablecustomer.AddCell(pcellscustomervalue);


            PdfPCell pcellsship = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ship", bodyFont));
            pcellsship.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsship.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;


            pcellsship.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsship.FixedHeight = 20f;
            ptablecustomer.AddCell(pcellsship);

            PdfPCell pcellcustomername = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_InvoiceSchema.PONumber, bodyFont));
            pcellcustomername.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellcustomername.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellcustomername.UseAscender = true;
            pcellcustomername.FixedHeight = 20f;
            ptablecustomer.AddCell(pcellcustomername);

            PdfPCell pcellsonumber = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_InvoiceSchema.InvoiceDate.ToShortDateString(), bodyFont));
            pcellsonumber.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsonumber.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;


            pcellsonumber.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsonumber.FixedHeight = 20f;
            ptablecustomer.AddCell(pcellsonumber);








            tableBP.AddCell(table);



            tableBP.AddCell(pdfpSp);



            string ShipAddress = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address1))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address1 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address2))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address2 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address3))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address3 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address4))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address4 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address5))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Address5 + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.City))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.City + ",";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.State))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.State + " ";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.PostalCode))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.PostalCode + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Country))
                ShipAddress += _InvoiceSchema.ShipAddress.Country + Environment.NewLine;

            float[] widthP = new float[] { 5f };
            PdfPTable tableP = new PdfPTable(1);
            tableP.WidthPercentage = 30f;
            tableP.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            tableP.SetWidths(widthP);


            PdfPCell pcellsProperty = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("   Ship To", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsProperty.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pcellsProperty.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellsProperty.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsProperty.FixedHeight = 22f;
            tableP.AddCell(pcellsProperty);


            PdfPCell pcellsPropertyvalue = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ShipAddress, bodyFont));
            pcellsPropertyvalue.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pcellsPropertyvalue.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            pcellsPropertyvalue.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsPropertyvalue.FixedHeight = 50f;
            tableP.AddCell(pcellsPropertyvalue);
            tableBP.AddCell(tableP);




            float[] widpf = new float[] { 20f };
            PdfPTable pdgpSp = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdgpSp.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pdgpSp.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            pdgpSp.WidthPercentage = 5.0f;
            pdgpSp.SetWidths(widpf);

            float[] wigdp = new float[] { 20f };
            PdfPTable pdfpghSp = new PdfPTable(1);
            pdfpghSp.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pdfpghSp.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            pdfpghSp.WidthPercentage = 5.0f;
            pdfpghSp.SetWidths(wigdp);


            tableBP.AddCell(ptablecustomer);

            tableBP.AddCell(pdgpSp);
            tableBP.AddCell(pdfpghSp);
            tableBP.SpacingAfter = 12f;



            doc.Add(tableBP);
            #endregion

            float[] widthM = new float[] { 2f, 2.3F, 8.3f };
            PdfPTable tableM = new PdfPTable(3);
            tableM.SetWidths(widthM);
            //tableM.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = 20f;
            tableM.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

            tableM.WidthPercentage = 100.0f;
            //tableM.h

            PdfPCell clHeader = new PdfPCell();
            clHeader.FixedHeight = 20f;

            PdfPCell pcellsitemname = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Qty", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsitemname.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsitemname.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

            pcellsitemname.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsitemname.FixedHeight = 20f;
            tableM.AddCell(pcellsitemname);


            PdfPCell pcellsDescription = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Code", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsDescription.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsDescription.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            // pcellsProperty.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            pcellsDescription.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsDescription.FixedHeight = 20f;
            tableM.AddCell(pcellsDescription);

            PdfPCell pcellsQty = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description", boldTableFont1));
            pcellsQty.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pcellsQty.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            pcellsQty.UseAscender = true;
            pcellsQty.FixedHeight = 20f;
            tableM.AddCell(pcellsQty);



            PdfPCell amtCell = new PdfPCell();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtpdfvalues.Rows)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["Parent"])))
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            int k = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtpdfvalues.Rows)
            {
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(dtpdfvalues.Rows.Count);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["Parent"])))
                {
                    k++;
                    PdfPCell descCell = new PdfPCell();

                    PdfPCell qtyCell = new PdfPCell();
                    PdfPCell rateCell = new PdfPCell();



                    descCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                    qtyCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                    rateCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                    amtCell.FixedHeight = 78;




                    if (i != k)
                    {
                        descCell.MinimumHeight = 335 / i;
                        qtyCell.MinimumHeight = 335 / i;
                        rateCell.MinimumHeight = 335 / i;
                        amtCell.MinimumHeight = 335 / i;

                        descCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                        qtyCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                        rateCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                        amtCell.FixedHeight = 78;



                    }
                    else
                    {

                        descCell.MinimumHeight = 335;
                        qtyCell.MinimumHeight = 335;
                        rateCell.MinimumHeight = 335;
                        amtCell.MinimumHeight = 335;

                        descCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                        qtyCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                        rateCell.FixedHeight = 78;
                        amtCell.FixedHeight = 78;


                    }

                    rateCell.Border = 0;
                    amtCell.Border = 0;
                    rateCell.Border = 0;
                    descCell.Border = 0;
                    qtyCell.Border = 0;









                    rateCell.BorderWidthLeft = 0.1f;
                    amtCell.BorderWidthLeft = 0.1f;
                    descCell.BorderWidthLeft = 0.1f;
                    qtyCell.BorderWidthLeft = 0.1f;
                    qtyCell.BorderWidthRight = 0.1f;
```

Comment: 532 lines of code and the bottom part is completely missing (count your brackets)? You should be able to pair this down to maybe 50 to 100 lines that can still reproduce the problem. Remove your proprietary DAL and just pop some strings in so that we can copy and paste your code, have it compile and we can see what you can see.